# ethminer never seems to mine - repeated DAG generation

Tags: mining, linux, gpu, ethminer, nvidia

I've installed geth and ethminer to get started mining. I've got an Ubuntu 16.04 box with a couple Nvidia TitanX cards. When I fire up ethminer like so...

> ethminer --no-precompute -G --opencl-device 1

It spends about 10 minutes generating a DAG file, then spits out some quick messages about initializing the miner, but then goes right back into generating another DAG file (and repeat). Here's the output from between the DAG file generations.

> Creating DAG. 100% done...miner  01:42:25.948|ethminer  Got work package:
>   miner  01:42:25.948|ethminer    Header-hash: 5179bc66dd92a61cc31cf9c0fb3460cb1c353dca87966cc2c9390fca61ecf233
>   miner  01:42:25.948|ethminer    Seedhash: 0823bb39dee602fcd155d60fcd7d3c489623497a91ce0f79475ef7f09390a2c3
>   miner  01:42:25.948|ethminer    Target: 000000000006bbd41383e0f5fbc3e27d35d69737ac3d585f83f0ec5b7c04f844
>   
>   ℹ  01:42:25.970|gpuminer0  workLoop 1 #cad4f4a9… #0823bb39…
>   
>   ℹ  01:42:25.970|gpuminer0  Initialising miner...
>   [OPENCL]:Using platform: NVIDIA CUDA
>   [OPENCL]:Using device: GeForce GTX TITAN X(OpenCL 1.2 CUDA)
>   miner  01:42:26.470|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #5179bc66… : 0 H/s = 0 hashes / 0.5 s
>   
> miner  01:42:26.471|ethminer  Grabbing DAG for #c3ddddc8…
>   [OPENCL]:Printing program log
>   [OPENCL]:
>   [OPENCL]:Creating one big buffer for the DAG
>   [OPENCL]:Loading single big chunk kernels
>   [OPENCL]:Mapping one big chunk.
>   [OPENCL]:Creating buffer for header.
>   [OPENCL]:Creating mining buffer 0
>   [OPENCL]:Creating mining buffer 1
>   DAG  01:42:33.455|ethminer  Generating DAG file. Progress: 0 %

I assume I should see mining and PoWhash messages (with a non-zero hashrate) once a DAG has been generated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh and it's probably worth adding that this is CUDA 7.5 and the 4.4.0-24-generic Linux kernel.

Comment: Is your node fully synced? Looks like you're trying to mine while syncing, which isn't going to work

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to mining I would suggest using Claymore Dual Miner. It is very easy and straight forward to run. And you shouldn't have to worry about the errors you're receiving anymore as the program will take care of everything and you wont need to worry about to syncing your node.